# First Bootstrap row is different from others

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a question/problem with my Bootstrap 4 page, as seen in the below screenshot. The first row is squashed, while the following rows scale to mobile. I've been unable to get the first row to act the same? Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Screenshot > https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePfLS.jpg

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><strong>Optus Singtel Pty Limited</strong></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">4GPlus &nbsp; 3G &nbsp; 2G</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">LTE 2600 &nbsp; LTE 700 &nbsp; WCDMA 2100 &nbsp; WCDMA 900 &nbsp; GSM 900 &nbsp; (LTE 900 proposed)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><strong>Vodafone Hutchison Australia Pty Limited</strong></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">3G &nbsp; 2G</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">WCDMA 900 &nbsp; GSM900</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><strong>nbn co Limited</strong></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">4G (NBN Fixed Wireless)</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">LTE 2300</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: change the classes of columns within first row from col-xs-4 to col-sm-4

Comment: Extra small grid always stay horizontal. Change col-xs-4 to col-sm-4 in first row.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the class you are using on your first row since it is a different size from the other two and the size you are using on the first one fitted on screen that's why it didn't act as the others did.

Try changing the class of the div tags on your first row into "col-sm-4"